# What kind of hardware requirements are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've this one:

- [What are the PC hardware requirements for OS X to run on?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/270/15)

and it's off-topic, however another one related to hardware requirements is on-topic:

- [Multiple monitors hardware requirements](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/274/multiple-monitors-hardware-requirements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware Recommendations was created for questions seeking a ***specific* hardware recommendation** given a set of *definitive* requirements. The OS X question was off topic, but the multiple monitor question was salvageable.

If the question is about general computing and hardware issues, it could be asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com); nevertheless, it is outside the scope of *this* site.

Answer (score 2):

The https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-are-the-pc-hardware-requirements-for-os-x-to-run-on question is asking what system requirements are needed for a hackintosh. There doesn't seem to be a hardware recommendation question hidden in there.

The [Graphics card that can support three monitors](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/274/multiple-monitors-hardware-requirements) question, though poorly worded, is actually asking for a graphics card recommendation to meet their requirements of three monitors and their usage pattern.